# how can i pass a value from a sub procedure to a function procedure....do i pass the whole subprocedure to the function procedure argument?

Tags: vb.net

Im a student doing an assignment, how do i pass the value from a sub procedure to a function procedure....i want to pass the value from decSubtotal to a function procedure named CalculateDiscount; check out my code--

```
 Private Sub CalculateSubtotal(ByVal _decTENTCOST As Decimal, ByVal _decRVCOST As Decimal, _
                              ByVal _decCABINCOST As Decimal)

    Dim decSubtotal As Decimal
    Dim intSiteType, intNumberOfNights As Integer

    intSiteType = cboSiteType.SelectedIndex()
    intNumberOfNights = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumberOfNights.Text)

    Select Case intSiteType
        Case 0
            decSubtotal = _decTENTCOST * intNumberOfNights
        Case 1
            decSubtotal = _decRVCOST * intNumberOfNights
        Case 2
            decSubtotal = _decCABINCOST * intNumberOfNights

    End Select

    lblSubtotal.Text = decSubtotal.ToString()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll call the function like this, (right after your End Select Statement, probably)

```
Dim MyValue = CalculateDiscount(decSubTotal)
```

Your CalculateDiscount might look like this:

```
Function CalculateDiscount(byval pSubTotal as Decimal) as Decimal

   ....

   return MyDiscountedAmount

End Function
```

In VB.NET, we only speak of "subs" and "functions". Both are sub-routines, also known as sub-procedures (to some). Functions always return a value, and subs never return a value.

Comment: Thanks. I realized that i wasnt assigning the right variables to eachother in the argument

Comment: Thanks again...I thought a sub procedure was different than a function procedure..Thanks for clearing that up. The requirements document for my assignment said to create a sub procedure so I was just creating a sub instead of function...That was a huge prob....lol

Comment: If you have covered reference vs. value/copy parameters, then he might want you to do ByRef pSubTotal in CaclculateDiscount. In that case, you COULD make CalcDiscount a Sub instead of a Function, and simply update the pSubTotal parameter. "ByRef" means... pass me a reference to the "real thing", and when I make updates to it the updates are seen by the calling code. "ByVal" means... pass me a copy of the parameter. If I make changes to it, the calling code does not see the changes. Figured I'd let you know